# jQuery: wrap newly created html

Tags: jquery, html-manipulation

I create HTML snippet on-the-fly:

```
$('<span/>').addClass(spanClass)
```

Is there a jQuery way to wrap this code into `<div>`?

Semantically I want to do:

```
$('<span/>').addClass(spanClass).wrap($('<div/>').addClass(divClass))
```

that does not work. So I just want following **jQuery-idiomatic** version:

```
function wrap(what, with) { return $(with).append(what); }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep in mind that your jQuery object is still referencing the new `<span>`, so if you're trying to insert it with a chained method, the `<div>` won't be inserted.

To overcome this, you'd need to traverse up to the new parent `<div>` first.

```
    // Traverse up to the new parent in order to append the <div> and <span>
$('<span/>').addClass(spanClass).wrap($('<div/>').addClass(divClass))
            .parent().appendTo('body');
```

You could also write it like this:

```
$('<span/>').addClass(spanClass).wrap('<div/>')
            .parent().addClass(divClass).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: first, it does not work, `wrap()` wraps nodes in DOM, $('<span/>') is not in DOM until I put it there. Second, if I'd use function I presented I would do `$('body').append(wrap(...))`

Comment: @user93422: First, yes it does work. [Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2Wnpc/) Second you'll get the same result using that method of `$('body').append(` *if* you don't bother to traverse up to the new `<div>`.

Comment: [...here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Wnpc/2/) using `$('body').append(...` without traversing. And [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Wnpc/3/) that works because it *does* traverse up to the new parent `<div>`.

Comment: @user93422: To be clear, when you do `$('<span/>')` you *are* creating a DOM element. When you wrap it with `$('<div/>')`, you now have a hierarchy of elements *that can be traversed* even though they're not yet inserted into the `document`.

Comment: aha, `.wrap()` returns the *wrapped* object indeed. my bad, it does work.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('<div/>', {'class': divClass}).append($('<span/>', {'class': spanClass}));
```

Comment: +1 for the use of the "props" object, but you should put `class` in quotes, or call it `className` to avoid reserved word issues.

Comment: how is it different from `function wrap(what, with) { return $(with).append(what); }`?

Comment: @user: Well, in that it does not use a separate function. Being *"jQuery idomatic"* also means to not break the function chaining that makes jQuery so convenient. Whether you call `foo.wrap(bar)` or `bar.append(foo)` is less important IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
$('<div/>').addClass(divClass).append($('<span/>').addClass(spanClass));
```

IE create your div first?

Comment: because I suspect there got to be a built-in in jQuery way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('<span/>').addClass(spanClass).wrap($('<div/>').addClass(divClass).html());
```

or

```
$('<div/>').addClass(divClass).append($('<span/>').addClass(spanClass));
```